# Parent selector for zen-coding

Tags: html, emmet

I just discovered zen-coding.

I have the following snippet of code I want to generate.

```
<div id="base">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="body"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>         
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with one line of zen-code

I know I can write

```
div#base>div#header>div#logo
```

this is where I get stuck, cause I don't know, how I can go back and add body and footer divs(siblings of header).

I want to figure out if/how this can be done in one line.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me with ZenCoding for Notepad++

```
div#base>(div#header>div#logo)+div#body+div#footer
```

Answer (score 0):

addition to Jonathon Bolster's answer:

other trick for climb up parent tag / tree:

- you can using operator

```
  circumflex accent: ^
```

from emmet ( successor of zencoding )

source:
http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

- or you can using

```
  less than symbol: <
```

from sparkup ( fork of zencoding )

source:
https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup