# zen coding multiple elements with children

Tags: html, css, emmet

I am trying out zen coding and cannot seem to replicate some HTML code I have laying around.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="home-page container clearfix news-article">
    <div class="box-round">
        <div class="cn tl"></div>
        <div class="cn tr"></div>
        <div class="br-title"><span></span></div>
        <div class="br-content pad15 clearfix">
            <cfoutput>#event.getView("data")#</cfoutput>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
div.home-page.container.clearfix.news-article > div.box-round > div.cn.tl + div.cn.tr + div.br-title > span
```

And I guess where I am stuck in is expanding multiple items each of which has a child element.

Specifically: my `<div class="br-title">` has a child element which is an empty `<span></span>` (added to see if I can replicate in zen) but it also has a "sibling" element `<div class="br-content pad15 clearfix">` which itself has a child element.

Any advice will be much appreciated. I did look up examples, and tried myself to resolve with no success, so I am curious how this can be done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, you can parenthesize elements with child selectors or use the parent operator (`^`):

**1. Parens `()`**

A nice way to avoid breaking the "flow" of you zen coding snippet. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132843/parent-selector-for-zen-coding) SO post.

`(div.br-title > span) + (div.br-content > cfoutput)`

Complete Snippet:

```
div.home-page.container.clearfix.news-article > div.box-round > div.cn.tl + div.cn.tr + (div.br-title > span) + (div.br-content > cfoutput)
```

**2. Parent Operator `^`**

Another option, as Sergey (he's the creator of Emmet, so you can probably trust him ;) ) pointed out in the comments.

`.br-title>span^.br-content>cfoutput`

Complete Snippet:

```
.home-page.container.clearfix.news-article>.box-round>.cn.tl+.cn.tr+.br-title>span^.br-content>cfoutput
```

*An additional note*

There's no need to include `div` before your `.class` names, you can just use `.classname` and Emmet will include a div (you do need to specify for other elements). A more concise Zen Coding snippet would be:

```
.home-page.container.clearfix.news-article>.box-round>.cn.tl+.cn.tr+(.br-title>span)+(.br-content>cfoutput)
```

Comment: @BoltClock Good point. Emmet is the successor to Zen Coding, but some people have not hopped on the bandwagon yet. OP's Zen Coding snippet does not work for me when copy/pasted directly into Emmet, so I wasn't sure. I've updated my post to clarify.

Comment: Another option is to use `^` operator:

`.br-title>span^.br-content>cfoutput`

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip @Sergey, i've updated my post to include your point. Also, thanks for ``Emmet`` :) It's saved me so much precious time!